# How to open an email with predefined attachment?

Tags: c++, shell, email, outlook

How can I open an email with predefined attachment. While using the following code I am getting an error from Microsoft Outlook 2013:

**Code:**

```
const auto addr = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Hi&Attach=\"D:\hello.txt\"";
```

or

```
const auto addr = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Hi&attachment=\"D:\hello.txt\"";
```

or

```
const auto addr = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Hi&attachment=\"D:\\hello.txt\"";

ShellExecute(0, "open", addr, nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

**Error:**

```
The command line argument is not valid. verify the switch you are using
```

Can anyone help me out here? Without attachment it works fine.
Is there any other way to open a file with attachment?

Thank you

Comment: Not all mail clients will accept attachments like that - but try double backslashes in the path to your document: `D:\\hello.txt`

Comment: What about `const auto addr = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=Hi&Attach=\"D:\\hello.txt\"";`? It seems to be the last one to try.

Comment: If you are only interested in supporting Outlook, [MAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/outlook-mapi-reference) could be an option.